# Searching for keywords in any order in solr?

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 4.6 for storing index and returning search results. I have requirement where i need to get same search results from solr for identical keywords but in reverse order using queries as below.

```
{sort=score+desc&df=text&q="test email"&q.op=OR&wt=javabin&qt=/select&fq=content_source:SharePoint&version=2&AuthenticatedUserName=ljangra@iwater.ie} hits=35 status=0 QTime=62
```

and

```
{sort=score+desc&df=text&q="email test"&q.op=OR&wt=javabin&qt=/select&fq=content_source:SharePoint&version=2&AuthenticatedUserName=ljangra@iwater.ie} hits=35 status=0 QTime=62
```

E.g. if i search for "email test" & "test email", i should get same search results which i am not getting currently. Is it default behavior of solr or am i missing anything?

Any help will be appreciated.

regards.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you specify your search string in quotes, such as `"test email"`, Solr performs a Phrase Search. You can specify the distance you want to search by using `~<distance>`, so `"test email"~2` would search for the two words within a distance of two between each other.

If you're using the (e)dismax query parser, you can also use the `qs` parameter to adjust the slop allowed between the terms.

Comment: I am using AND between keywords such as "test AND email" or "email AND test" & its working. Only point i am not convinced is should i use brackets () for this such as ("test AND email") or ("email AND test"). What is the difference between two options i.e. with or without brackets.

Comment: Brackets are used to group boolean statements, i.e. `(test AND email) OR foo` or to group clauses for a field: `field:(test email)` (instead of `field:test field:email`).

Comment: So does it mean that it will work properly without using any brackets as well?

Comment: Yes. And without quotes as well, if you're just interested in documents that contain "test" and "email" somewhere in them.